# Linear Algebra subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether the set $W= \{(2a-2,3b,2a-3b)\}$ is a subspace in $\mathbb R^3$ 
Describe the set.

I know that in order for a set to be a subspace, it must be closed under multiplication and addition.. How would I go about showing this? Thanks